# How do I reorder a vector during a Thrust transformation?

Tags: cuda, nvidia, thrust

How could i transform this simple code to thrust code?

```
for (i=0;i<cA-rA;i++)
    sn[i]=c[n_index[i]]-sn[i];
```

More Info:
cA and rA are const integers so we can concider as an 'n'= cA-rA
sn : array of float(n)
n_index : array of int(n)
c : array of float(cA)

My problem is with the n_index[i] that points to the element of the C array.
thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can implement this by fusing `thrust::transform` with a "gather" operation using a `permutation_iterator`:

```cpp
#include <thrust/device_vector.h>
#include <thrust/iterator/permutation_iterator.h>
#include <thrust/transform.h>
#include <thrust/sequence.h>
#include <thrust/functional.h>

int main()
{
  size_t n = 100;

  // declare storage
  thrust::device_vector<int> sn(n);
  thrust::device_vector<int> n_index(n);
  thrust::device_vector<int> c(n);

  // initialize vectors with some sequential values for demonstrative purposes
  thrust::sequence(sn.begin(), sn.end());
  thrust::sequence(n_index.begin(), n_index.end());
  thrust::sequence(c.begin(), c.end());

  // sn[i] = c[n_index[i]] - sn[i]
  thrust::transform(thrust::make_permutation_iterator(c.begin(), n_index.begin()),
                    thrust::make_permutation_iterator(c.end(), n_index.end()),
                    sn.begin(),
                    sn.begin(),
                    thrust::minus<int>());

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: actually i m not getting the same results as it should any idea why?

Comment: If you edit your original post to include more details about the code you're trying to port, it may be possible to tailor a solution. In particular, the solution depends on the values of ```cA```, ```rA```, ```c```, and ```n_index``` which are unknowns in your post.

Comment: just edited it, thanks again.
If you try to uncomment // sn[i] = c[n_index[i]] - sn[i] and save it to an sn2 for examples and crosscheck the two arrays they are different.

Comment: @iassael could you please post your solution ? :) I have the same problem! Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2):

I tried the first one and wasn't getting the correct results. the second permutation_iterator needs to be at the end of *BOTH* vectors.

Try the following correction:

> ```
> // sn[i] = c[n_index[i]] - sn[i]
> thrust::transform(thrust::make_permutation_iterator(c.begin(), n_index.begin()),
>             thrust::make_permutation_iterator(c.end(), n_index.end()),
>             sn.begin(),
>             sn.begin(),
>             thrust::minus<int>());
> ```